# Advanced C and C++ compiling: unable to compile the example program mentioned in the book

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, compiler-errors

I'm reading the book named "Advanced C and C++ compiling", by Milan Stevanovic

The following is the snapshot from the book, followed by the problem I'm facing.

---

Concept illustration: Demo Project

The development environment used to build this simple project will be based on the gcc compiler running on
Linux. Listings 2-1 through 2-3 contain the code used in the demo project.

Listing 2-1. `function.h`

```
#pragma once
#define FIRST_OPTION
#ifdef FIRST_OPTION
#define MULTIPLIER (3.0)
#else
#define MULTIPLIER (2.0)
#endif

float add_and_multiply(float x, float y);
```

Listing 2-2. `function.c`

```
int nCompletionStatus = 0;
float add(float x, float y)
{
    float z = x + y;
    return z;
}
float add_and_multiply(float x, float y)
{
    float z = add(x,y);
    z *= MULTIPLIER;
    return z;
}
```

Listing 2-3. `main.c`

```
#include "function.h"
extern int nCompletionStatus = 0;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    float x = 1.0;
    float y = 5.0;
    float z;
    z = add_and_multiply(x,y);
    nCompletionStatus = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Demo Project Preprocessing Example:

The gcc compiler provides the mode in which only the preprocessing stage is performed on the input source files:

```
gcc -i <input file> -o <output preprocessed file>.i
```

Unless specified otherwise, the output of the preprocessor is the file that has the same name as the input file and
whose file extension is `.i`. The result of running the preprocessor on the file `function.c`looks like that in Listing 2-4.

Listing 2-4. `function.i`

```
# 1 "function.c"
# 1 "
# 1 "
# 1 "function.h" 1
# 11 "function.h"
float add_and_multiply(float x, float y);
# 2 "function.c" 2
int nCompletionStatus = 0;
float add(float x, float y)
{
    float z = x + y;
    return z;
}
float add_and_multiply(float x, float y)
{
    float z = add(x,y);
    z *= MULTIPLIER;
    return z;
}
```

More compact and more meaningful preprocessor output may be obtained if few extra flags are passed to the gcc, like

```
gcc -E -P -i <input file> -o <output preprocessed file>.i
```

which results in the preprocessed file seen in Listing 2-5.

Listing 2-5. `function.i` (Trimmed Down Version)

```
float add_and_multiply(float x, float y);
int nCompletionStatus = 0;
float add(float x, float y)
{
    float z = x + y;
    return z;
}
float add_and_multiply(float x, float y)
{
    float z = add(x,y);
    z *= 3.0;
    return z;
}
```

Obviously, the preprocessor replaced the symbol `MULTIPLIER`, whose actual value, based on the fact that the
`USE_FIRST_OPTION` variable was defined, ended up being `3.0`.

---

### Problem:

When I compile the program as is using gcc, following is the error I am facing
Snapshot from my terminal.

```
gcc -i function.c -o function.i
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option '-i'

gcc function.c -o function.i
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o:
In function '_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to 'main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

$pwd
/home/adminuser/advance_compiling
$ll
total 20
drwxrwxr-x  2 adminuser adminuser 4096 Jan 10 23:51 ./
drwxr-xr-x 26 adminuser adminuser 4096 Jan 10 23:57 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 adminuser adminuser  216 Nov 15 08:58 function.c
-rw-rw-r--  1 adminuser adminuser  163 Jan 10 23:33 function.h
-rw-rw-r--  1 adminuser adminuser  257 Dec 28 06:46 main.c
```

How do I get rid of this and proceed in learning the course?
Please suggest.

Comment: is this `gcc -E -P -i <input file> -o <output preprocessed file>.i` really from the book?

Comment: You just missed a great opportunity to learn how to look up the right flag to use.

Comment: Yes `gcc -E -P -i <input file> -o <output preprocessed file>`is from the book?

Comment: You should have tried `gcc --help` and `man gcc` or reading [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) - faster than asking a question here

Comment: It is in the book indeed, it's probably an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was a technical reviewer of the book and the author asked me to post this explanation on his behalf:

> The error you found is indeed an error, introduced in the very late stage of book proofreading/editing. Sorry for stepping on it + for book errata still not being printed out (will happen some time soon).

Comment: Is the book errata available now?

Answer (score 7):

`-i` is not a valid command line option - I'm not sure where the book got it from. In order to just run the preprocessor, you should use the option `-E` instead.

Comment: maybe book uses different compiler than gcc

Comment: That was my first thought, but the text in the question seems to be directly quoted from the book.

Comment: I got confused because the OP posted the preprocessed file, I thought he wanted to compile the code, not to run the preprocessor on it, I thought he succeeded in that step, but anyway where did the `-i` come from? if it's from the book, may be it was valid in previous versions of `gcc`.

Comment: I just looked it up in Google Books, and that is definitely a direct quote from the book. It was published less than a year ago too, so an old version of GCC isn't to blame. (Not that I think they would have changed a major flag like that anyways.) Who knows...

Comment: I have a recollection that GCC 2.x used `-i` for preprocessing

Comment: Maybe his system has some other compiler linked to `gcc` and he doesn't realize

Comment: That's kinda what I am leaning towards, without reading more of the book to see if it explains how the environment was set up. Very sloppy for a textbook though. I noticed that the publisher's page has a way to submit errata, maybe I'll comment there later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
gcc -E -P function.c -o function.i
```

without the `-i` option, it's not a `gcc` option.

**note**: this answer was fixed after I realized that have misunderstood the question, so i fixed to keep it and not delete it, but **Katie** did answer it before I did.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the `.i` output file in the book's example, it seems the error is in the utility itself.

Instead of using `gcc`, use `cpp`. gcc uses cpp (The C Preprocessor) under the hood to handle macro expansion and header inclusion. The output of cpp is a `.i` file for c source code and `.ii` for c++.

```sh
cpp function.c > function.i
```

Answer (score -4):

Try the following code:

```
function.c

#include "function.h"
int nCompletionStatus = 0;
float add(float x, float y)
{
    float z = x + y;
    return z;
}
float add_and_multiply(float x, float y)
{
    float z = add(x,y);
    z *= MULTIPLIER;
    return z;
}

main.c

    //#include "function.h"
    extern int nCompletionStatus;
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        float x = 1.0;
        float y = 5.0;
        float z;
        z = add_and_multiply(x,y);
        nCompletionStatus = 1;
        return 0;
    }

Now execute:
gcc function.c main.c

otherwise 
gcc -c function.c
gcc function.o main.c
```